# Why one requires getElementById and the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, html

Why does this work

```
app.prints(address,list.options[list.selectedIndex].value);
```

but this doesn't?

```
app.prints(status,macAddress);
```

JavaScript

```
var hey = 5;
var app = {
    createList: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            list.options[i] = new Option(hey + i, "mac" + i);
        }
        app.prints(address, list.options[list.selectedIndex].value);
    },
    prints: function (location, message) {
        location.innerHTML = message;
    },
    manageConnection: function () {
        var macAddress = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
        app.prints(status, macAddress);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Don't panic! All this 
    code looks intimidating but eventually it  will make sense. -->
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ECMA.js"></script>
    <title>My LCD code</title>
</head>

<body onload="app.initialize();">
    <p>Welcome to the LCD software</p>
    <select id="list" onchange="app.prints
    (address,list.options[list.selectedIndex].value);"></select>
    <div id="address"></div>
    <button id="connect" onclick="app.manageConnection();">Connect</button>
    <div id="status">hi</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Status is not defined and hence that might not work. You have declared in html but u must do document.getElementById("status") for it to  get recognized in js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that a global `status` variable [has already been defined by the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.status) to represent the text in the status bar. And, browsers don't allow a reference to the element to replace it.

To avoid the naming conflict, you can rename the element.

But, you really shouldn't depend on automatic globals for `id`s. Not all browsers implement the feature, and some only in certain modes.

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var address = document.getElementById('address');
app.prints(address, list.options[list.selectedIndex].value);
```